# Initelij missing JavaEE?

Tags: java, jetbrains-ide

Why isnt there a Java Enterprise so I can use webapplikations?

[image: Picuture of my Intelij]

Comment: IntelliJ Community Edition does not have a Java EE (and other popular Framework) support. You can, however, configure your project manually.. add corresponding dependencies, xml configurations, or whatever is needed for you. You can even configure the Tomcat plugin to explode the `.war` into your local Tomcat instance.

Answer (score 0):

You have several options for WebApp development there in the left column.

- Java Enterprise
- Spring
- Quarkus
- Micronaut
- MicroProfile
- Grails

Or you can find a Maven / Gradle archetype

Or you can make a vanilla Java/Groovy/Kotlin app and add your own framework manually

Comment: OpenJDK plans to support Java 8 through [at least May 2026](https://adoptopenjdk.net/support.html) - longer than even Java 11.  Oracle, while hating Java developers, still expects to have [free public updates and auto updates of Java SE 8 indefinitely](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/java-se-support-roadmap.html) or give at least 18 months of warning if they drop it.